# Convert array of objects and their properties to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I tried several of the map functions but could not find a proper way to get what I want. Here is the case:

```
Object {Results:Array[3]}
   Results:Array[3]
       [0-2]
            0:Object
                   id=null     
                   name: "Rick"
                   upper:"0.67"
            1:Object
                   id="00379321"     
                   name:null
                   upper:"0.46"
            2:Object
                   id="00323113"      
                   name:null
                   upper:null
```

I want my final result to look like this. I wanted all null values to be removed and all the entries tied up like this in an object.

```
var finalResult = ["Rick","0.67","00379321","0.46","00323113"];
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a fixed array for the keys, because the properties of an object have no order and the order is relevant.

```js
var data = [{ id: null, name: "Rick", upper: "0.67" }, { id: "00379321", name: null, upper: "0.46" }, { id: "00323113", name: null, upper: null }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    ['id', 'name', 'upper'].forEach(function (k) {
        if (a[k] !== null) {
            result.push(a[k]);
        }
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it gives me an error stating data.forEach is not a function

Comment: which user agent do you use?

Comment: didnt get you by user agent

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: its working fine with chrome 51.0.2704.106 m for windows.

Comment: i modified the input. i checked the console.log and it shows me as mentioned in the question now. can you please have a look

Comment: OP's `null` is not string.

Answer (score 3):

```
_.chain(a)
.map(function(x) {return _.values(x)})
.flatten()
.filter(function(x) {return x != null;})
.value()
```

Comment: Note that the "null" values in the example code are not actually `null`, but rather a string. Also, it's generally better to provide an explanation of the code, especially to people who are not familiar with the library.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan to people who are unfamiliar with library I always suggest to read docs first.

Comment: Okay, but take a look at [answer], specifically *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.* It's obviously up to you how helpful you want to be, but this will likely end up on the Low Quality review queue due to being a code dump.

Comment: @Andrey- this still shows null values at the final output when i do console.log(a); also i dont see any errors. am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: @Patrick I don't know what nulls you have exactly. Normal null value in JS is a value on its own, but in your example you have "null" as string. Adjust my code accordingly (4th line)

Comment: @Andrey- i checked the typeof for the null value. it shows object. in the console.log, i see null. No double inverted commas... just null

Comment: @Andrey- yes, and i modified the input. i checked the console.log and it shows me as mentioned in the question now. can you please have a look

Answer (score 3):

Small modification for @andrey's code (requires lodash.js)

```
var a = [{id:null, name: "Rick", upper:"0.67"}, {id:"00379321", name:null, upper:"0.46"}, {id: "00323113",name:null, upper:null}]
_(a)
.map(function(x) {return _.values(x)})
.flatten()
.without(null)
.value()
```

Comment: my apologies. The input in the console shows a bit different than wat i had earlier mentioned. Can you please have a look and let me know

Comment: I updated my answer. I used different data in the array. Now it contains the same data and the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Another underscore solution, similar to the other underscore solutions, but uses [**reject**](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) and the [**isNull**](http://underscorejs.org/#isNull) predicate:

```
var result = _.chain(data)
    .map(_.values)
    .flatten()
    .reject(_.isNull)
    .value();
```