# Loop through an array of objects and get only a few objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, underscore.js

I have this following array of Objects.

```
[Object, Object, Object]
    0:Object
       name: "Rick"
       Contact: "Yes"
       id: 1
    1:Object
       name:"Anjie"
       Contact:"No"
       id: 2
    2:Object
       name:"dillan"
       Contact:"Maybe"
       id:3
```

Now, i want only the name and Contact objects out of it. How can i get that. Also, in other case, i want name and id. Can someone let me know how to achieve this please.

for e.g. only name and Contact should give this result.

```
[Object, Object, Object]
    0:Object
      name: "Rick"
      Contact: "Yes"
    1:Object
      name:"Anjie"
      Contact:"No"
    2:Object
      name:"dillan"
      Contact:"Maybe"
```

Comment: What don't you know how to do? Seems like a pretty simple problem. Where are you stuck?

Comment: [This previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248004/convert-array-of-objects-and-their-properties-to-array) of yours gets you much of the way there.

Comment: name and Contact are properties of the Object. They are Strings, which are of course objects in themselves. But it would have been clearer to describe them as properties. Anyway you can use Array.map to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
var objs = objs.map(function(obj) {
    return {
        name: obj.name,
        Contact: obj.Contact
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can loop through it manually:

```js
var objs = [{
       name: "Rick",
       Contact: "Yes",
       id: 1
}, {
       name:"Anjie",
       Contact:"No",
       id: 2
}, {
       name:"dillan",
       Contact:"Maybe",
       id:3
}];

var newObjs = [];

for ( var i=0, len = objs.length; i < len; i++ )
{
    newObjs.push({
        name: objs[i].name,
        Contact: objs[i].Contact
    });
}

console.log(newObjs);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access some properties of an object in array than simply you can use a for loop and passing value of i like:-

```
for(var i=0;i<object.length;i++){
   object[i].name // give you name
   object[i].contact // give you contact do whatever you want to do with this
}
```

or simply write a function that make a separate object from your object in array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use underscore's [**map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [**pick**](http://underscorejs.org/#pick):

```
var result = _.map(data, item => _.pick(item, 'name', 'Contact'));
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution coould be one with a given data array and keys array. The wanted properties are mapped in a new array.

```js
function getWithKeys(array, keys) {
    return array.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        keys.forEach(function (k) {
            o[k] = a[k];
        });
        return o;
    });
}

var array1 = [{ name: "Rick", Contact: "Yes", id: 1 }, { name: "Anjie", Contact: "No", id: 2 }, { name: "dillan", Contact: "Maybe", id: 3 }],
    array2 = getWithKeys(array1, ['name', 'Contact']),
    array3 = getWithKeys(array1, ['name', 'id']);

console.log(array2);
console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map()` and return array of new objects with deleted property. To create copy of object you can use `(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()))`

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Rick", Contact: "Yes" }, { id: 2, name: "Anjie", Contact: "No" }, { id: 3, name: "dillan", Contact: 'Maybe' }];

var result = data.map(function(e) {
  var r = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)));
  delete r.id;
  return r;
});

console.log(result)
console.log(data)
```

Or you an use `Object.assign({}, e)`

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Rick", Contact: "Yes" }, { id: 2, name: "Anjie", Contact: "No" }, { id: 3, name: "dillan", Contact: 'Maybe' }];

var result = data.map(function(e) {
  var r = Object.assign({}, e);
  delete r.id;
  return r;
});

console.log(result);
console.log(data);
```